# OpenERP custom module on mobile

Tags: odoo

I am making a custom module in OpenERP. I have a list(tree) view and a form view. I can view and edit records. 
When I take the mobile view of the same module, I can see the main menu and browse to the sub menu, but no list view or form view is visible. All I can see is a blank page. Is my list definition worng?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>    
<tree string = "Camera">    
    <field name = "a"/>    
    <field name = "b"/>    
</tree>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that after a menu option is selected, the following menu is a simple list with the name of each record.

It may be that you don't have any record yet.

Or it may be that you don't have a `name` field on the object model and views. Add that field (make it `required`) or, alternatively, set the object's `_rec_name` attribute (example: `_rec_name = 'a'`).

Comment: I have 4 fields in my model - shot_id, camera_name, location, d_o_n(dropdown), i_o_e(dropdown). I have 4 records in the module that I can view/add/edit/delete from the webclient6.1.   But none of them are seen in the mobile client. Actually in the mobile if there are no records in a module, then it shows "There are no records to show". But for my module even this message is not displayed. It just displays a blank page.

Comment: Tried to add `_rec_name = 'camera_name'` to the model?

Answer (score 1):

- OE Mobile View is read-only mode
- It does not have any type of view(like, tree or for, or kanban), It just show the view of record and show you have value. It hos wht name filed valeu on list then if you click on it it open detail view which show thw other detail. and yes try and add the record on your model.

Thank You

Comment: I have 4 records in the module that I can view/add/edit/delete from the webclient6.1.